# Is possible insert a new row in a complex view created from 2 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, union, sql-insert

I've read Oracle Language Reference and There is nothing about this situation So here we go...

I've coded a complex view from 2 tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NOFORCE VIEW vw_emps_hist_50_b
AS
   SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, 
          job_id, department_id
   FROM   employees_history
   WHERE  department_id = 50
   UNION
   SELECT employee_id, TO_CHAR(NULL), TO_CHAR(NULL),
          job_id, department_id
   FROM   employees_history_2
   WHERE  department_id = 50
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Now I'm trying to insert a new row using the view:

```
INSERT INTO vw_emps_hist_50_b
VALUES      (2005, 'Dexter', 'Morgan', 'ST_CLERK', 50);

Error que empieza en la línea: 46 del comando -
INSERT INTO vw_emps_hist_50_b
VALUES      (2005, 'Dexter', 'Morgan', 'ST_CLERK', 50)
Error en la línea de comandos : 46 Columna : 13
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
01732. 00000 -  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Is there any way to insert this row into both tables? or Can I chose which table I want to insert this new row?

Comment: It's necessary to use "UNION" clause

Comment: @GurV . . . I prefer `cast(NULL as varchar2(255))` or something like that.  But it creates a `NULL` value with a character data type.  Yes, `NULL` can have a type.  (I am periodically reminded of this when I try to create a table using a query that has just `NULL` in a column.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and yes.  You cannot insert directly into the view; it is too complicated.  Instead, you can create an "instead of" trigger on the view itself.

That is, you can specify what to do when the view is updated.  One place to start with this is the Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) on the subject.

Comment: My god You are a genius!!! I've read about instead of trigger 3 or 4 months ago but I didn't remember this option! I will read of triggers again. Thanks alot for your help. Past 8 minutes I will mark your answer

Answer (score 0):

The executed operation violating the policy  since the view derived from more than 1 table and you are trying insert operation on that view.